# Ubuntu 20.04 - Gnome Tweaks - Installed shell themes aren't showing in drop down list

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

I am following Linux Scoop's tutorial on installing the Orchis theme and I was able to install and choose the themes for Applications, Cursor and Icons but I am not able to choose "Orchis" in the drop down menu for Shell.

I followed the same steps that Linux Scoop did and I also copied the theme to Home/.themes and also usr/share/themes. I tried restarting my pc and it still doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

This is the tutorial I followed: https://youtu.be/qC0mnGprbeM?t=480

Comment: Did you install user-themes extension or not?

Comment: Yes I did. I am able to click on the drop down menu for "Shell" but only "WhiteSur-Dark/Light" and "Yaru" show up.

Comment: What is the output of `ls .themes`

Comment: In Home/.themes there is too many to list but they are all of the Orchis themes. In usr/share/themes it also has all of the Orchis themes plus the default themes like Adwaita, Aurora, Ceanice, Crux, etc.

Comment: Ok then `ls .themes/Orchis` change Orchis with actual directory name and provide the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "change Orchis with actual directory name" but the output when I ls .themes/Orchis is: "cinnamon, gnome-shell, gtk-3.0, index.theme, plank, COPYING, gtk-2.0, gtk-4.0, metacity-1, xfwm4".

Comment: Ok above output is what I am looking for. Now what's the output of `ls .themes/Orchis/gnome-shell`

Comment: "assets, no-events.svg, no-notifications.svg, pad-osd.css process-working.svg"

Comment: there is no gnome-shell.css file. Hence it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `install.sh` script from the extracted downloaded zip file `Orchis-theme-master.zip`

if the package `sassc` is not installed, you will notice this. "line 74: sassc: command not found"

```
~/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master$ ./install.sh
sassc needs to be installed to generate the css.
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 166: has_command: command not found
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 168: has_command: command not found
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 170: has_command: command not found
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 172: has_command: command not found
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 174: has_command: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-compact'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-light'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-light-compact'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-dark'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-dark-compact'...
/home/pratap/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master/core.sh: line 74: sassc: command not found

Done.
```

when the package sassc is not available, the script cannot generate gnome-shell.css file.

you should install the package first with below command

```
sudo apt install sassc
```

and then run the script again.

```
~/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master$ sudo apt install sassc
[sudo] password for pratap: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsass1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsass1 sassc
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 695 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,801 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsass1 amd64 3.6.3-1ubuntu1 [684 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 sassc amd64 3.6.1-2 [10.4 kB]
Fetched 695 kB in 10s (66.7 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libsass1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 164042 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsass1_3.6.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsass1:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package sassc.
Preparing to unpack .../sassc_3.6.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sassc (3.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libsass1:amd64 (3.6.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up sassc (3.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
pratap@antarctica:~/Downloads/Orchis-theme-master$ ./install.sh
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis'...
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-compact'...
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-light'...
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-light-compact'...
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-dark'...
Installing '/home/pratap/.themes/Orchis-dark-compact'...

Done.
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome